# Tags beyond saving

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

- save (merged into [saving](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/saving))
- save-as (merged into [saving](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/saving))
- [saving](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/saving)

These tags need to die.

Comment: And could we merge these as well, ready for tomorrow's tag cleanup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BY TROGDOR. THIS HAS BEEN BURNINATED!

Answer (score 9):

*Save* what? Not this tags, right?

[image: Save, saving and save as are vague verbs of saving something in some piece of software, they should use the name of that piece of software as tag]